# Docker connect SQL Server container non-zero code: 1

Tags: sql-server, docker, apple-m1

I'm trying to create a SQL Server container from a `docker-compose.yml` but when I run it, it directly stops with some errors. Note: it's running on an Apple M1 chip with docker Preview

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  sql-server-db:
    container_name: sql-server-db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports: 
      - "1433:1433"
    environment: 
      SA_PASSWORD: "ApplePassDockerConnect"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

The errors I'm getting:

> sql-server-db | /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr: Invalid mapping of address 0x40092b8000 in reserved address space below 0x400000000000. Possible causes:
>
> sql-server-db | 1) the process (itself, or via a wrapper) starts-up its own running environment sets the stack size limit to unlimited via syscall setrlimit(2);
>
> sql-server-db | 2) the process (itself, or via a wrapper) adjusts its own execution domain and flag the system its legacy personality via syscall personality(2);
>
> sql-server-db | 3) sysadmin deliberately sets the system to run on legacy VA layout mode by adjusting a sysctl knob vm.legacy_va_layout.
>
> sql-server-db |
>
> sql-server-db exited with code 1

Comment: I've filed a suggestion on this topic (SQL Server support for Apple's M1 chips) at MS's feedback site.

It can be found here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/949650e5-3248-ec11-a819-0022484bf651

Answer (score 26):

You cant really use `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest` containers on M1 because MSSQL DB does not support ARM architecture. The only way I found - is to use Azure SQL container that supports ARM and can be run on M1.

Here my `docker-compose.yml` config example:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
    # Database instance
    mssql:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest
      volumes:
        - events_mssql:/var/opt/mssql
      ports:
        - 1433:1433
      environment:
        - ACCEPT_EULA=1
        - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Passw@rd

volumes:
    events_mssql:
```

You will be able to connect to this DB using username: `sa`, password: `Passw@rd` and database: `master`. If you want other db name - you can create a new one [using SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/deploy-portal#create-a-new-database): `CREATE DATABASE TestDB`

This database has the same API as MSSQL DB, so it works with `pyodbc` (not supported on M1) and `pymssql` libraries.

If you are using it locally on your M1 machine - consider using `pymssql` library for connection to Azure SQL DB. Here my answer on issue with `pyodbc` https://stackoverflow.com/a/66919686/11515610

Comment: @Eric what exactly doesn't work? What error do you have?

Comment: The indentation seems to be off. But is ok, I don't need this anymore. I am switching to postgres and I was able to make that work.

Comment: I tried this for a test proj on my M1 mac and it worked fine.

Comment: using Docker environment variables in `.sql` file does not seem to work for me. Is `$(MSSQL_DB)` the correct format?

Comment: @keligijus you are right. I just realized that this script doesn't work in an azure container and it was intended for mssql container. I updated the answer and added the recipe on how to create a different DB in the Azure container.

Comment: Btw there is discussion is going on in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/668) regarding ARM arch support of mssql db

Comment: Azure Edge does not support GeoPoints (because the docker container does not come with any DotNet runtime)

Comment: I've filed a suggestion on this topic (SQL Server support for Apple's M1 chips) at MS's feedback site.

It can be found here: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/949650e5-3248-ec11-a819-0022484bf651

Comment: An important issue of this approach is that the mssql-tools are not available. This is the note from https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-sql-edge: [!NOTE] sqlcmd tool is not available inside the ARM64 version of SQL Edge containers.

Comment: I've tried to use azure-sql-edge but getting Error: Common Language Runtime(CLR) is not enabled on this instance & enabling this setting is not supported on the azure-sql-edge. So anyone knows any workaround for this?

Comment: I wonder if the image has changed. I was having success with Azure Edge, but now I'm getting the same segfault as I do with MSSQL.

Answer (score 24):

Docker now supports the **experimental feature of using Rosetta** (interpretation layer) for emulating x86 applications on amd64 architecture. This fixed the issue for me. [image]

Comment: This was able to get me up and running on my M2 chip: https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/sql-server-management-studio-mac

Comment: This is the way. (for now)

Comment: This worked for me. Enable the Rosetta checkbox, restart Docker, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Image for Apple Chip M1 are not containerised yet, but we can use **azure-sql-edge.**

I have also tried MSSQL image for Apple M1 Chip, but same error.

Using azure-sql-edge, I am able to use MSSQL on Apple BigSur OS with M1 Chip

You can go through this article
https://medium.com/geekculture/docker-express-running-a-local-sql-server-on-your-m1-mac-8bbc22c49dc9

Don't forget to mark it Answered, if it helps you.

Comment: This worked for me on a Mac M2, as well. !

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, Azure SQL Edge Server is a workaround for the M1 issues of MSSQL Server. However, at the moment, the `:latest` tag of Azure SQL Edge Server has the same segfault as MSSQL server. `mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:1.0.6` works on M1, though.

```
docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=1' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password' -p 1433:1433 --name azuresqledge -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:1.0.6
```

Comment: It is not working with this version, I have tried it
```version: "3.1"
services:
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:1.0.6
    container_name: mssql
    volumes:
      - events_mssql:/var/opt/mssql
      - ./setup.sql:/usr/config/setup.sql
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Passw@rd
      - MSSQL_PID=Developer
      - MSSQL_DB=events_service
      - MSSQL_USER=SA
      - MSSQL_PASSWORD=Passw@rd
      - MSSQL_DB_AUDIT_LOG=events_service_audit_log

volumes:
  events_mssql:```

Answer (score 1):

```
The latest version of Azure SQL Edge works for me on M1.
```

```
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>
```

Answer (score 1):

On MachBook M3 Max - `enable Use Rosetta for x86/amd64 emulation on Apple Silicon`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So...this may not be related to your particular issue. I have a feeling it won't fix it for you, because your issue sounds much lower level (as you suspect) but it's worth a shot.

I tried copy-pasting your exact docker-compose file and running it on my machine (windows desktop), I also get `exited with code 1`.

The only thing that seemed to fix it was using a more complex password.

I tested this multiple times in a row...I tested your password, and it failed. I tested a complex password, and it worked fine.

So I suggest using a more complex password. The password I tested with was `6Xy3LkV7!9lo2^h`

Comment: that didn't fixed the issue but thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can use azure-sql-edge image.

After a couple of hours, I am able to find this alternative:

After opening Docker and removing containers and images, ran in terminal:

docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge:latest

sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=1" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Pass123" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -e "MSSQL_USER=SA" -p 1433:1433 -d --name=sql mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge

Then use "localhost,1433" as server, "SA" as username, "Pass123" as password.(Without quotes)