# Pyodbc on M1 Macs

Tags: sql-server, odbc, pyodbc, pymssql, apple-m1

I am trying to connect to a Microsoft sql server database using pyodbc. I keep getting the error

> Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Checking `pyodbc.drivers()` gives no result

I installed the Microsoft ODBC driver according to the instructions provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15):

I ran `odbcinst -j` which yields

---

```
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini 
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini 
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/pawannandakishore/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

---

but when I got to `/etc`, I cannot find either `odbcinst.ini` or `odbc.ini`. They are seem to be in `opt/homebrew/Cellar/`

I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: As per [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (macOS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos): _The Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server on macOS is only supported on the x64 architecture. The Apple M1 is not supported._ Maybe try FreeTDS until they do?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning this is factually wrong. The official pages says "... only supported on the x64 arch through version 17.7. Apple M1 (ARM64) support was added starting with version 17.8..."

Comment: @gmarais, the quote was correct when it was written a year ago. Microsoft didn't even release ODBC Driver 17.8 for SQL Server until four months later in [July 2021](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-17-8-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/2596530).

Answer (score 8):

#### UPD:

You actually can use `pyodbc` in the container but the container should be built and executed in the x86_64 arch container. In order to do this, you need to add the `platform` either to `docker-compose.yml` or provide an argument during container run (when using docker).
You need to make sure that you are building a container using [buildx](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/)!

Docker:

- `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t myimage .`
- `docker run --platform linux/amd64 myimage bash`

Docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    image: myimage:latest
    build:
      context: ./
    platform: linux/amd64
```

---

#### Original answer:

It's true that `pyodbc` does not support ARM architecture. I'm using `pymssql` on my M1 in order to connect to MSSQL server.

1. You need to install the system requirement `freetds-dev`. For alpine container, it will be `apk add freetds-dev`
2. In pip requirements add `pymssql` package.
3. Test connection with simple script:

```py
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server='mssql', user='SA', password='Passw@rd', database='master')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT 1;""")
```

4. SqlAlchemy connection should look like this

```py
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    f"mssql+pymssql://{MSSQL_USER}:{MSSQL_PASSWORD}@{MSSQL_HOST}/{MSSQL_DB}?"
)
```

If you need to run MSSQL database on M1 - here my answer on this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/66919852/11515610

Related links:

- [Adaptive server connection failed (DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991190/adaptive-server-connection-failed-db-lib-error-message-20002-severity-9)
- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pymssql
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pymssql/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pymssql-python-development?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html

Comment: There will be a performance hit if you use amd64 container. It's probably better to use FreeTDS.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed the ODBC Driver is not yet supported on M1 Macs.

But! you can use the `pymssql` library in order to connect and make queries. This works perfectly on my M1 MacBook Pro 13"

#### Install FreeTDS via Homebrew

```
brew install freetds
```

#### Install using pip

Then use pip (or pip3) to install `pymssql`:

```
pip3 install pymssql
```

#### Start coding!

Then, just import it to your code! Here is an example :)

```py
import os
import pymssql

server = <your_server>
user = <username>
password = <password>

conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "<your_database>")
c1 = conn.cursor()

c1.execute('SELECT * FROM <your_table>')
data = c1.fetchall()

print(data)

conn.close()
```

[Here are the docs](https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pymssql_examples.html) from `pymssql` to more details.

---

Update Mar 16 2023: Updated pymssql docs link

---

Update May 25 2023: From Microsoft official docs:

> Apple ARM64 support was added starting with version 17.8. The architecture will be detected and the correct package will be automatically installed by the Homebrew formula.

Indeed ODBC Driver is now supported for ARM architecture laptops (M Chip series)

Comment: Thanks for this! Yep it worked with pymssql

Comment: Note that you can use FreeTDS with pyodbc too. But your example with pymssql is also good!

Comment: Tried this and got the error "ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymssql, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects"

Comment: "Indeed the ODBC Driver is not yet supported on M1 Macs" - no longer true?

Comment: Link is dead....

Comment: Link fixed! sorry

Comment: Amazing! I went through a lot of MS/Azure docs and this was the only thing that worked though I used `conda install pymssql`

Answer (score 2):

I tried on my M1 2020 Big Sur, it works

```
brew install unixodbc
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.9/include"
```

If you are using pycharm, make sure the LDFLAGS and CPPFLAGS is set up correctly