# import pyodbc - symbol not found in flat namespace '_SQLAllocHandle'

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

trying to import pyodbc into a python script on mac m1 monterey

```
import pyodbc
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/shivaji/wire/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyodbc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SQLAllocHandle'
```

Tried reinstalling homebrew and unixodbc and following this answer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/705302/sql-server-on-mamp.html

```
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
brew install autoconf automake libtool
brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
brew install unixodbc

sudo CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/unixodbc/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib/" pecl install sqlsrv
sudo CXXFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/unixodbc/include/" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/lib/" pecl install pdo_sqlsrv

ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1m /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl
```

Comment: Does your Mac have an M1 chip?  As I understand it, the Microsoft mssql homebrew recipe doesn't support the M1 chip yet.

Comment: damn yeah, would you have another recommendation to connect to mssql in python on an M1?

Comment: This post suggests using FreeTDS/: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896068/pyodbc-on-m1-macs